# Ghost Image file using FSArchiver for Full-Disk Encrypted OS Drive

Tags: backup, encryption, disk-image

Trying to make a ghost image of my full-disk encrypted Ubuntu OS drive. Normally I've used FSarchiver for years. Great tool. But lately, something strange is happening.

I have full disk encryption enabled on my Ubuntu 20.04 system. I have tried to make an FSarchive file using the 'savefs' method from it. Normally this spits out a neat little .fsa file about 10 GB or less. This time... it just keeps copying data. More and more. I finally stopped the fsarchive process when it created a file that was 55 GB. My entire disk is only using 22 GB, so something is wrong.

I tried using SystemRescueCD and also booting from Ubuntu's 20.04 distro. Both resulted in runaway massive files being copied and I don't know why. I created a virtual-machine installation of Kubuntu 20.04 with full-disk encryption, then booted into SystemRescueCD on that image and tested my steps for making the fsarchive back. No problem. I'm lost why this isn't working.

Here are my steps:

1. Boot into the Linux distro via a bootable USB.
2. Find what the currently booted system lists as my encrypted installed disk device to be. This is typically /dev/sdb5

```
$ fdisk -l
```

3. Open the encrypted drive.

```
$ cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdb5 MyEncrypted-partition
    Enter passphrase for /dev/sdb5:
```

4. Mount the opened encrypted drive.

```
$ mkdir /media/MyEncrypted-partition
$ mount /dev/mapper/MyEncrypted-partition /media/MyEncrypted-partition/
```

Sometimes I've got an error related to LVM2_membership and this is what I do to solve that.

The error:

```
    mount: unknown filesystem type 'LVM2_member'
```

To fix:

```
$ apt-get install lvm2
```

[Or when using Gentoo: It’s already available, just load the kernel modules ]

```
$ /sbin/modprobe dm-mod
$ /sbin/lsmod | grep dm_crypt
    dm_crypt               11331  1
```

Then I have to run:

```
$ vgscan
    Reading all physical volumes.  This may take a while...
    Found volume group "vgkubuntu using metadata type lvm2
```

Then:

```
$ vgchange -ay vgkubuntu
    2 logical volume(s) in volume group "vgkubuntu" now active
```

Now to check what is seen by the system:

```
$ lvs

  LV       VG         Attr         LSize   Origin Snap%  Move Log Copy%  Convert
  root     vgkubuntu  -wi-a-----   460.57g                                      
  swap     vgkubuntu  -wi-a-----   15.89g
```

5. Back on track, now mount that full-disk encrypted OS drive as read-only.

```
$ mount -o ro  /dev/mapper/vgkubuntu--root /media/MyEncrypted-partition/
```

6. Check that it's all there and good...

```
$ ls /media/MyEncrypted-partition/

bin   etc         initrd.img.old  lost+found  opt   sbin     sys  var
boot  home        lib             media       proc  selinux  tmp  vmlinuz
dev   initrd.img  lib64           mnt         root  srv      usr  vmlinuz.old
```

7. Create the ghost image of the hard drive

```
$ fsarchiver -j4 savefs  /media/other-drive/filename.fsa  /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root
```

I have tried pointing fsarchiver to the mounted opened-encrypted drive directory instead, using the command below, but I get this error message:

```
$ fsarchiver -j4 savefs  /media/other-drive/filename.fsa /media/MyEncrypted-partition/
    oper_save.c#1200,oper_save(): /media/MyEncrypted-partition/ is not a valid block device
```

Out of desperation, I tried making a .tar file of the disk contents and it had the same thing with producing something bigger than was currently used on the drive. I do not know what I'm doing wrong. Please help.

Comment: Why do you copy from the mapped device, and not from the mount point if you already mounted it there?

Comment: @Sebastian When I try to run the command: fsarchiver -j4 savefs  /media/other-drive/filename.fsa /media/MyEncrypted-partition/, I get the error message: "oper_save.c#1200,oper_save(): /media/MyEncrypted-partition/ is not a valid block device".

Comment: Well, from what I see fsarchiver indeed expects a block device as source, not a mounted filesystem. The logical volume management might interfere here, but I'm not knowledgeable enough to help there, I avoid using lvm for exactly that reason. It may also be that it's simply not possible to use fsarchiver with an encrypted volume, due to the mapping involved to decrypt the data. If the archiver cannot "see through" the encryption, it will likely just copy all the partition, so you end up with an archive the size of your partition. From what you describe it seems that's what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

After much analysis, I believe I have figured out the problem. The file-system on target drive I wanted to make a backup archive for had been thoroughly corrupted. Honestly I'm shocked. ALL the superblocks were corrupted. None of them worked. None could be read or mounted.

This likely explained the numerous system crashes I experienced randomly without any warning. (Though I still suspect I may have a graphical hardware problem, or at the very least an nvidia-drivers problem.)

Ultimately I completely formatted the drive and reinstalled Ubunutu 20.04 on it. Then everything worked super well. Afterward I loaded into an Ubuntu Live boot-usb drive, simply mounted the newly created encrypted drive through dolphin, then remounted it from commanding as read-only, then performed the fsarchiver backup.

```
$ fsarchiver -j4 savefs  /media/other-drive/filename.fsa  /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root
```